# Client socket throws connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused) after some time of work on Android

Tags: android, sockets, wifi

I have Android app.
App sends data from one device to other via socket connection.
All works great, but sometimes client app throws exception:
failed to connect to /192.168.88.243 (port 9700): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
Wifi connection is fine.

The puzzle lays in next.
device with 192.168.88.243 is correctly achieved by long period of time, but it becomes "failed to connect" unexpectedly. 
I have checked IP of this device, it still the same.

Can someone, please describe why this happens.

Comment: No, this is not the same issue. My issue is that device becomes "failed to connect", not problematic from start of streaming.

Comment: Nevertheless the issue is exactly the same. Nothing was listening at the IP:port you tried to connect to. You should investigate the server side of this. It is exiting, or closing its listening socket.